# SQL display only entries with increasing trend

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `MySQL` database, I'm in need of writing a SQL to display the `purchase items` which have `increasing trend over` the selected period.

The below SQL display the volume of `purchases` of all items over the `selected period`.

```
SELECT
    ITEM_ID
    ITEM_NAME,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE)='6',NUM_PURCHASE,0)) AS PUR_JUNE,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE)='7',NUM_PURCHASE,0)) AS PUR_JULY,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE)='8',NUM_PURCHASE,0)) AS PUR_AUG,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE)='9',NUM_PURCHASE,0)) AS PUR_SEP
FROM
    TRANS_DETS
WHERE
    TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-10-01'
GROUP BY
    ITEM_ID,
    ITEM_NAME
```

Could I request help to write up my requirement please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `having` clause.  Assuming that you mean that there is an increase from one month to the next:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE) = '6', NUM_PURCHASE, 0)) AS PUR_JUNE,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE) = '7', NUM_PURCHASE, 0)) AS PUR_JULY,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE) = '8', NUM_PURCHASE, 0)) AS PUR_AUG,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(TRANS_DATE) = '9', NUM_PURCHASE, 0)) AS PUR_SEP
FROM TRANS_DETS
WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-10-01'
GROUP BY ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME
HAVING ((PUR_JUNE < PUR_JULY) AND (PUR_JULY < PUR_AUG) AND
        (PUR_AUG < PUR_SEP));
```